# C++ static member function vs lambda overhead

Tags: c++, lambda, unique-ptr

I have some kind of templated base class

```
template<typename Derived>
class Base { };
```

and want to store derived instances of it in a list.
For that I use a `using derived_handle = std::unique_ptr<void, void(*)(void*)` alias.

When I now add a derived instance to the list i cound use a static member function as deleter

```
class foo {

  template<typename Derived, typename... Args>
  void add_base(Args&&... args) {
    auto derived = derived_handle{new Base{std::forward<Args>(args)..., &foo::_deleter<Derived>};

    _derived.emplace_back(std::move(derived));
  }

private:

  template<typename Baser>
  void _deleter(void* base) {
    delete static_cast<Base*>(base);
  }

  std::vector<derived_handle> _derived{}; 

};
```

or a lambda

```
class foo {

  template<typename Derived, typename... Args>
  void add_base(Args&&... args) {
    auto deleter = [](auto* derived){
      delete static_cast<Derived*>(derived);
    }

    auto derived = derived_handle{new Base{std::forward<Args>(args)..., std::move(deleter)};

    _derived.emplace_back(std::move(derived));
  }

private:

  std::vector<derived_handle> _derived{}; 

};
```

Are there any advantages/disadvantages of the lambda version I should be aware of?

Comment: Why this kind of architecture? What prevents you from storing a vector of `std::variant<Derived1, Derived2, Derived3>` (or something in that manner, be it boost::variant, std::any, or anything else, including hand-crafted custom code)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Time for a frame challenge!

You've made some bad decisions in that code. Most people who use `unique_ptr`, even in a polymorphic context, don't need custom deleters at all. The only reason you do, is because of your type erasure, and that's only there because `Base<A>` and `Base<B>` are unrelated types.

If you really need `Base<T>`, have it inherit from an *actual* polymorphic (and non-templated) base class with a virtual destructor. Then you don't need `unique_ptr<void>` (a really bad code smell), and you can actually use your list in a type-safe manner.

Comment: Taking into account the custom deleters are there just for the sake of casting back to the original type, I'd dump the heap allocation (no gain as vector does that anyway) and go with variant or any other properly done type erasure, see my comment to the original post...

Comment: @alagner It depends on whether the set of types is homogeneous and compact enough to make a centralized `variant` definition a good idea, and on whether shared ownership semantics are actually needed.

Comment: Agreed, but note that a. I wrote "other properly done type erasure" b. the OP actually uses unique_ptr, not shared_ptr or am I missing sth?

Comment: Yeah, misread that.